# How to Verify the content of the description which is present line by line in selenium

Tags: selenium

The code is like:

```
<section>
<h3>Ready for a better way</h3>
<p>He delved into the infant art of animation with the 1911 film Little             followed its success by adapting an episode of his comic strip</p>
<h3>Ready for a better way studies</h3>
</section>
```

Tried with `driver.findelement(By.xpath()).gettext().equals()` but getting

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [null] but found[] value.
```

Comment: please provide the code tried to check this issue

Comment: Used like this also

if(driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjRepoProp
.getProperty("homepageDescriptionFirstText_XPATH"))).getText().equals(TextProp.getProperty("HOMEPAGE_FIRSTLINETEXTDESCRIPTION"));
    
when manually changed description in code then also scripting showing true(i.e application text as :Ready for a better way

in code used as string and i changed the description as 'Ready for a better way1234' )

Comment: Used like this also

if(driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjRepoProp
.getProperty("homepageDescriptionFirstText_XPATH"))).getText().equals(TextProp.getProperty("HOMEPAGE_FIRSTLINETEXTDESCRIPTION"));
    
when manually changed description in code then also scripting showing true(i.e application text as :Ready for a better way

in code used as string and i changed the description as 'Ready for a better way1234' )

Answer (score 0):

As per comment, please avoid using the if condition. Let say if 'if' condition is not satisfied simply it does not enter into if and moves on to next.. so here we are not getting any exception which is expected. Good to use Assertions

> Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected);

You need to provide what is actual values means which we get by driver and expected value which we need.

```
  Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("homepageDescriptionFirstText_XPATH"))).getText(), TextProp.g‌​etProperty("HOMEPAGE_FIRSTLINETEXTDESCRIPTION"));
```

For more info on Assertions please look [here](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/Assert.html)

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Hi Murali,

Thanks for info.

If i checked what you mentiond i'm getting - java.lang.AssertionError: expected [null] but found [Ready for a better way]

Regards,

Comment: so expected null means this TextProp.g‌​etProperty("HOMEPAGE_FIRSTLINETEXTDESCRIPTION") retrieving null value. simplt print it before assertion to cross check

Comment: u can also try once providing direct text/string instead this

Comment: Got the result , I putted value in string within TextProperty files, that's the issue.